# dynamic html table with complex JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an aspx page, which is calling a ajax method to return a JSON object containing arrays of Countries.

I want to loop through the data and create

- COUNTRY

within a table for each entry.

From what I can see, my code looks good, but i'm not getting any results written to my div.

I've set up a Fiddle with data and would appreciate some assistance.

http://jsfiddle.net/L3s6c0yx/1/

and here is the JS code

```
var tdata = "{"d": "[{\"Countries\":[\"Cyprus: 3\",\"Panama: 3\"]},{\"Countries\":[\"Malaysia:     1\",\"Malaysia: 2\"]},{\"Countries\":[\"Tanzania: 3\"]}]"}";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "",
data: tdata,
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (result) {
    tdata = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);

    var response = '',
        indicator = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < tdata.length; i++) {
        response += '<div class="item">' +

            '<table style="height: 300px;">' +
            '<tbody>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td><label>Countries</label></td>' +
            '<td><ul>' + $.each(tdata[i]['Countries'], function (value) {
            response += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        response += '</ul></td></tr>' +
            '</div>';
    }
    $('#countries').append(response);
 }
});
```

[image: Image showing the UL]

Comment: any error in console? try putting alert(response) and also check if $('#countries').length > 0. Please also try  alert(result.d);

Comment: as in fiddle  alert(result.d); is undefined

Comment: I get the countries output, but it's not creating the li. I've added a screen grab of what is rendered

Comment: result.d is what c sharp returns as the json object.

Comment: try adding alert inside like                                     $.each(tdata[i]['Countries'], function (value) {  alert(response); alert(value)
            response += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });

Comment: to be frank i prefer using jquery template to create dynamic content based on json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get this inside your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tdata.length; i++) {
    response += '<div class="item">' +

    '<table  class="table table-user-information" style="height: 300px;">' +
    '<tbody>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td><label>Countries</label></td>' +
    '<td><ul>';

    $.each(tdata[i]['Countries'], function (index, value) {
        response += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
    });

    response += '</ul></td></tr>' + '</div>';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3s6c0yx/6/

You were adding $.each function to your string which returns arrays. Hope this is what you were looking for.